# caching model(DTO) classes for later use

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching

I am working on an application which uses foursquare and other server api-s for getting information from the internet. But I have to use some datas when the application is not connected to the internet, I need a method which easily saves these datas from the internet store them on the "disk" as a cache if the phone lost connectivity. Basically I want to store some of my model classes like:

VenueCategory contains a name, id, images(~10), weather reports for 7 days, venues.
A Venue contains images, rating, name, category, categoryImage, address, phone number and open hours schedule. 
A water report contains date, max, min temperature, wind, ....

I am thinking on 3 methods but I don't know which is the best for my problem, maybe you can give me better ideas.

1. Database
   Pro:
   I get a nice representation from my datas. 
   Cons:
   It is hard to modify if the application is live. 
   I don't need a new table for the venue category, a table is to much for 1 record inside it.
   I have to do a lot of query, insertion, deletion, update, etc.
2. Serialization
   It is easy if I can found a nice way I just say write the whole class to disk and read from disk.(I've never tried)
3. Plist: (just like the database)

My final question is that, what do you think which is the best and why? Do you have better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to approach this is (IMO), is to have your DTOs comply to [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and serialize them using [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and deserialize them using [NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can use [AutoCoding](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AutoCoding) for that, which automatically implements the required methods in NSCoding with no effort at all.

Comment: I will try this, looks like the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using CoreData?  That was the first solution that came to my mind.

CoreData is (by default) based on SQLite and is in my opinion the defacto standard for persisting objects in iOS.

Comment: thanks for your answer :), it is a good idea but I've used coredata 1 years ago and I have a lot of bad experience with it, I can't access the data easily using multiple threads.